# How make two way binding numericUpDown to member class

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, c#-2.0, numericupdown

I need twoway binding configClass.RaMsize to numericUpDown.

```
BindField(this.upDownRamSize, "Value", configClass, "RaMsize");//all right

this.upDownRamSize.Value = 1213;// configClass.RaMsize - not change - it's bad!
```

Method:

```
public static void BindField(Control control, string propertyName,
               object dataSource, string dataMember)
        {
            Binding bd;

            for (int index = control.DataBindings.Count - 1; (index == 0); index--)
            {
                bd = control.DataBindings[index];
                if (bd.PropertyName == propertyName)
                    control.DataBindings.Remove(bd);
            }
            control.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that `ConfigClass` looks like:

```
public class ConfigClass
{
    public decimal RaMsize { get; set; }
}
```

So change 
            `control.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember);` 
to:

```
control.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Test:

```
BindField(this.upDownRamSize, "Value", configClass, "RaMsize");

this.upDownRamSize.Value = 1213;// configClass.RaMsize will also have 1213
```