# NumericUpDown value binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem. How to bind a **ItemsSource** property to a NumericUpDown? This way it does not work. Thx!

```c#
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="100"
                                Header="Amount"
                                MaxWidth="{Binding MinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <mahApps:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                       Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshValuesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </mahApps:NumericUpDown>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**

FIRST: Cantidad (Spanish) = Amount (English)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make two way binding numericUpDown to member class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709126/how-make-two-way-binding-numericupdown-to-member-class)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Do you have a specific error, i.e. the output for the binding ItemsSource, or is that working and the internal bindings not working?  Consider running Snoop to see which data bindings have failed.

Comment: What I am trying to do is: I have a list of items and I want to change the "Amount" using numericupdown. When you change a "Amount", a command is executed that recalculates all prices. I need to bind each numericupdown to each "Amount" of item. Go to edit to see more code and image.

The error: Cannot resolve property "Amount" in data context of type "System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Amount property is defined in the same class as the Articles property you should bind to the DataContext (DataContext.Amount) of the DataGrid:

```
<mahApps:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding DataContext.Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                   Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshValuesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</mahApps:NumericUpDown>
```

If the Amount property is defined in the data object (Article or whatever you call it) class it is simply:

```
<mahApps:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Amount}">
```

**Edit:** You should also set the UpdateSourceTrigger of the Binding to PropertyChanged:

```
<mahApps:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thx for response. I already tried those two ways and it did not work. Amount is an Article (class) property. Articles is observableCollection that I use in the ItemSource.

Comment: Make sure that the property is *public* and of type double.

Comment: If I use a simple column <DataGridTextColumn                                          Header = "Amount"
                                         Binding = "{Binding Amout}" />
it works perfectly. Of course with this I only manage to show a value and not change it.

Comment: Set the UpdateSourceTrigger of the Binding to PropertyChanged. I edited my answer.

Comment: Go to EDIT: I put two columns with the "Amount" property. When I add an item to the grid, by default I choose an "Amount", and add it. The first column shows the value, but the second does not.

Comment: Remove the RelativeSource part. It should be Value="{Binding Cantidad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"